# Is there some clever way of finding out this SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, orthogonality

I need to find the singular value decomposition of 
$$\pmatrix{a&-b&0\\b&a&-b\\0&b&a}$$

I already determined sigma to be:
$$\Sigma = \pmatrix{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}&0&0\\0&a&0\\0&0&\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$$

Now I was wondering whether there some something else that I was missing to this question other than just continuing as usual, to find $V$ and $U$?

EDIT

So trying the old method:

The the matrix be $A$. Then $A^TA$ is
$$\pmatrix{a^2+b^2&0&-b^2\\0&a^2&0\\-b^2&0&a^2+b^2}$$

The first two eigenvectors are

$$v_1=\pmatrix{\frac{4}{\sqrt{17}}\\0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}}\\
v_2=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}
$$
However the third eigenvector seems to be $(0,0,0)^T$ which cannot be right? Right?

Comment: Unless something else is explicitly asked in the problem statement, you need to find three matrices: you've already found one of them, so you need - as you said - to find the remaining two.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Well $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers. I'm now having trouble finding the third eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda = a^2-b^2$ because it seems that it equals 0 but that cannot be right? I need it to have norm 1.

Comment: If you obtain the zero eigenvector, then it seems that the corresponding eigenvalue is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that $A^TA$ looks like this? My calculations show that, for example, $(A^TA)_{22}=2b^2+a^2$.

Answer (score 0):

We write $$A^TA = \begin{pmatrix}m&0&-n\\0&m+n&0\\-n&0&m\end{pmatrix}$$with $m=a^2+b^2$ and $n=b^2$.

The obvious eigenvectors are $(1,0,1)^T$ for the eigenvalue $m-n=a^2$; $(1,0,-1)^T$ and $(0,1,0)^T$ for the eigenvalue $m+n=2b^2+a^2$.